# Resize all images according to screen resolution before loading a page

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, resize

I cannot find the correct solution for me, none of what I tried is working :(

I need:

before showing page content get screen resolution and then, according to it, resize all `img`-s on a page.

Ok, what I've tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(window).load(function() {

 var img = document.images;

 if (screen.width <= 699) {  

   for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {


         img[i].height = 200px;


         img[i].width = 200px;
   }

   }

 })


</script>
```

Comment: You can use [breakpoints](http://xoxco.com/projects/code/breakpoints/) or [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but I have very simple HTML page with only some images and one case: res > 700 and res < 700

Comment: You should read about Responsive Webdesign. http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design

Comment: Take a look at [viewport units](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css-viewport-units/), although this would only work if you're fine with only supporting updated browsers.

Comment: I know about responsive design, but due to a simplicity (it's actuallu one html page) I don't want to use it, is there a simple way jsut to change 2 parameters of image using javascript? Should be something really silly and simple..

Comment: In principle your code looks like it should work, but CSS Media Queries are both easier and more responsive. eg. just `@media (max-width: 699px) { img { width: 200px; height: 200px; } }` and done. This is based on window size—it's almost never a good idea to make layout decisions based on screen size.

Comment: Can anybody tell me why the hell this code is not working??

`<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
resize();
});

function resize(){ 

document.getElementById("pic").width=200;
document.getElementById("pic").height=200;

 
 
    }
  </script>`

Comment: There are a number of issues here. First off, are you using jQuery? The above code is mostly plain JavaScript, and the question is tagged as "JavaScript". But there's one use of jQuery: `$(window).load(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some very old fashioned JavaScript should do the trick.

```
<script>
if(screen.width > 699) {
    document.write('<style>img { width: 200px; height: 200px; }</style>');
}
</script>
```

Although rethinking your design philosophy would be better! Remember that some people might not have their browser maximised, or might want to set their own zoom settings.

Comment: Note: Be careful using `document.write`. If it's used after the page has loaded, it overwrites the entire page. As a rule, it's safer to use the DOM to edit the page.